# #SQLite This query statement does not work as I thought. What should I do

Tags: c++, database, sqlite

```
const static char* QUERY_UPDATE_ROUTE_ADDRESS = "UPDATE [PRouteAddrTable] SET [addressLanguage] = ?, [iso] = ?, "   \
                                                "[country] = ? , [state] = ?, [city] = ? , [cityCenter] = ?, "      \
                                                "[street] = ? , [street2] = ?, [houseNo] = ? , [zip] = ? "          \
                                                "WHERE RouteID = ? AND WptUseType = ? AND Lon = ? AND Lat = ?";
```

When this query is executed, the table is empty. So I think the table should be empty even after executing the query statement. But there is one record. I seem to be thinking wrong.

Please Help me

Comment: What is happening with your code?  Obviously, if there are no matching records, then the query would not do anything.

Comment: That information is enough. I will try to find myself. :)